# Jquery $.post default function on success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, .post

Is there a way to run a function every time a $.post function completes successfully?

e.g. I have:

```
$.post(ROOT + 'Ajax', { 
    call: 'Enquiry->setEnquiryUrgency', 
    enquiryId: enquiryId, 
    urgencyId: value
}, function(data) {
    $('#generalError').modal('hide')
    clearTimeout(saveErrorTimeout)
    $('#enquiryType button').html(text);
})
```

Instead of writing the lines:

```
$('#generalError').modal('hide')
clearTimeout(saveErrorTimeout)
```

Every time I do a `$.post`, I'd like those lines in a custom function somewhere to run when ever a `$.post` is called.

Perhaps something to do with extend or prototype (both of which I am unfamiliar)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [ajaxSuccess](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/):

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
    //...
});
```

This will run everytime an `AJAX` request completes successfully.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to make it apply to only certain AJAX requests?

Comment: @imperium2335 filter request type using ajaxOptions type: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/#ajaxSuccess1  e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/Fc4FQ/

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha I can't see where it shows how to use that :(. Would I need to set something on the $.post calls that I want to follow what I put in ajaxSuccess? Which I assume would then be available in the object I get with ajaxSuccess.